# Adding a click to isPointinPath

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have three rectangles in a canvas.

When my mouse is in the path of the orange rectangle, the green one appears. I want to change it to when the mouse is in orange shape **AND** clicked.

Just to avoid confusion, I took `green(ctx)` out of the init function THOUGH I left function `green(ctx)` as a reference. It serves no purpose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Created with Ai->Canvas Export Plug-In Version 1.0 (Mac) -->
<!-- By Mike Swanson (http://blogs.msdn.com/mswanson/)        -->
<!-- and MIX Online  (http://visitmix.com/)                   -->

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>testclick</title>
  <script>

    function init() {

      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      tan(ctx);

      orange(ctx);

      canvas.onmousemove = function (e)
        {
            var canvas = e.target;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // This gets the mouse coordinates (relative to the canvas)
            var mouseX  =  e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            var mouseY  =  e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;


            // Replay the rectangle path (no need to fill() it) and test it
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(663.3, 254.3);
            ctx.lineTo(516.0, 254.3);
            ctx.lineTo(516.0, 176.7);
            ctx.lineTo(663.3, 176.7);
            ctx.lineTo(663.3, 254.3);

            if (ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(417.3, 320.7);
                ctx.lineTo(113.3, 320.7);
                ctx.lineTo(113.3, 0.0);
                ctx.lineTo(417.3, 0.0);
                ctx.lineTo(417.3, 320.7);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(60, 127, 60)";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.restore();

            }

        }
    }

    function tan(ctx) {

      // tan/Path
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(393.3, 422.7);
      ctx.lineTo(0.0, 422.7);
      ctx.lineTo(0.0, 52.7);
      ctx.lineTo(393.3, 52.7);
      ctx.lineTo(393.3, 422.7);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 238, 191)";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }

    function green(ctx) {

      // green/Path
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(417.3, 320.7);
      ctx.lineTo(113.3, 320.7);
      ctx.lineTo(113.3, 0.0);
      ctx.lineTo(417.3, 0.0);
      ctx.lineTo(417.3, 320.7);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(60, 127, 60)";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }

    function orange(ctx) {

      // orange/Path
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(663.3, 254.3);
      ctx.lineTo(516.0, 254.3);
      ctx.lineTo(516.0, 176.7);
      ctx.lineTo(663.3, 176.7);
      ctx.lineTo(663.3, 254.3);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(240, 89, 41)";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }


  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="664" height="423"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain your problem... it's not clear what you want. Include relevant code **only**.

Comment: you already fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the color to change when clicked simply replace:

```
canvas.onmousemove
```

with

```
canvas.onclick
```

**[A fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/WSz9d/)** (I hope I understood you correctly here..)

Comment: That's for the `click` event, right? He could still use the `mousemove` event to apply his "orange shape" stuff, but avoiding any clicking processing inside of it.

Comment: @AlejandroIván to be honest the question is a bit unclear to me. Maybe OP can shed some more light on this. In any case he can keep the mousemove and process the pointInPath result differently.

Comment: sorry if my question was unclear. the change suggested did work. I am not changing the color, but adding the green shape when the orange one is clicked